# Perforce troubles "file not under client's root" error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, perforce

I am adding a project to perforce via VS2010 but I keep getting this error `'file' not under client's root` for all the files in the project. I can't seem to figure this out.

Here is what I am doing:

1) Open VS2010 project which is not in perforce yet.

2) I select add the solotion to perforce (from File > Source Control > Add Solution menu).

3) I select a new workspace. It brings up the properties of the workspace. The root folder is default to c:\Users\My.Name. I change this to the folder where my project is. I also change the view so it points to say depot\main\new_project.

It seems to have added the project but when I checkin file it just doesn't work! It give this error for all files that `'file not under client's root'`.

I also go to perforce directly and check the settings of the corresponding workspace. In dashboard it display an error:

```
P4V is having trouble translating the location "c:\Users\user.Name\Documents\Code\My_Project" to a valid workspace location. To filter using this location, drag the folder from the workspace tree to the workspace folder field or include the depot location in your workspace view.
```

Can somebody give me any pointer why this just doesn't work?

**Update**
My workspace mapping is this

```
Client:  omega
Owner:   User.Name
Root:    C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Omega
LineEnd: local
View:
         //depot/main/omega/...     //omega/...
```

Comment: Can you post your workspace mapping?

Comment: @Dennis I updated OP with workspace mapping.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `c++`?

Comment: @DerMike good point, I removed it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you get this error while the "Pending" Tab is open, the following could be your problem!  You may not be seeing your entire filter (ie. some of the filter may be out of view).   Mouse over your Window Pane Border underneath the filter until your cursor changes so that you can expand the Filter Window Pane.  There is a filter that could be there that says, "Files that match any of the following file paths:" Make sure that you don't have a file path selected that is incorrect.  Either remove the filter or choose "Current depor or workspace tree selection".

Comment: I've spent one day on this god damned problem. The p4v GUI is just horrible, this filters thing was completely hidden for me and if it weren't for you answer I wouldn't have know in even exists. So thank you very much! No I just have to figure out why p4v thought it might be a good idea to create a filter without me asking it ...

Comment: yeah it's been a while... but if this was the right answer, please mark it as so?

Comment: I too, after an hour of messing with my Workspace's settings, finally ready this answer.  Yup - just a Pending + Filter problem!  Easy solution - thank you for noticing this ridiculousness and posting the solution!  Yet another reason why we only use Perforce where/when the parent-company forces us to - just about every VCS system I've used is some to a *lot* better.  Ugh.

Comment: OMG! I have spent hours deleting and recreating workspaces, getting files into the wrong directories and cleaning them up. I ALMOST deleted the whole depot over this! +1 and please mark this as the ANSWER!! Hidden f*cking filters!! Unbelievable.

Answer (score 4):

What I believe is that you have a different path for your client and your code is in different path. From you P4V error I see that the path is:

```
c:\Users\user.Name\Documents\Code\My_Project
```

But your client root path is:

```
C:\Users\User.Name\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Omega
```

In above scenario, the path only upto "C:\Users\User.Name\Documents" is common, after that your client root and your project root differs. If you want to check in code from your My_Project folder, change the client root to point to that.   You can do so on command line by

```
p4 client <client name>
```

Or change it in Workspace view of P4V.

Also, make sure to use "" around your path since it has folder name with space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we add export P4CLIENT=steve_SIA_development to our bash profile this shouldn't happen right?

Comment: @Winnemucca - Correct. Provided you are exporting the correct p4 client. Also, make sure that you change your bash profile if you are updating your client or explicitly set the p4 client if you work on multiple p4 clients

Answer (score 1):

One 'oops' mistake you can make is to have the wrong workspace selected in Visual Studio 2012. Just did that and spent a few minutes scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that Perforce is having problems with the spaces in your path.  Try putting quotes around it.

From http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/03_using.html:

> Spaces in filenames, pathnames, and identifiers Use quotation marks to
>   enclose files or directories that contain spaces. For example:
>   "//depot/dev/main/docs/manuals/recommended configuration.doc" If you
>   specify spaces in names for other Perforce objects, such as branch
>   names, client names, label names, and so on, the spaces are
>   automatically converted to underscores by the Perforce server.

Comment: I changed my path c:\omega but I get similar error. I adds the file (from VS2010) but when I checkin I get an error message `No files to submit.
Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -c 8'.`

Comment: If I try to add these checked out files directly from perforce I get this error `warning: cannot submit from non-stream client` I have used perforce before but not the latest version and just don't know what the streams are

Comment: When you say you changed the path, do you mean you changed it for the root? And if so, did you copy/move the project to be located within c:\omega?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor I moved the code to c:\omega my PC than changed the root folder for my p4 workspace to c:\omega. The project view is still `//depot/main/omega/...     //omega/...`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error message showing during project build. 
What helped was deleting .suo file and reloading the project as described in [How does Visual Studio's source control integration work with Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261525/how-does-visual-studios-source-control-integration-work-with-perforce)

Answer (score 0):

Check the path specified in the client Root. If this is not a valid path then you encounter this error

```
Root:   /a/b/c/d
```

If this is not a valid root you end up getting the following error

```
Path '/a/b/c/d/...' is not under client's root '/a/b/c/d'
```

Just correct the path pointed to by Root and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

This exact problem was related to my "PENDING VIEW". It had a search filter set for the default workspace at the time, and any time I switched to a different workspace it would show the error dialog.

The deal was I had changed the workspace name, and the filter was no longer valid.

I cleared the filter (in the pending view) and the error disappeared.