# VS2010 with Perforce error: Path '...' is not under client's root '...'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, perforce

I am getting the following error after opening my project in Visual Studio 2010 after build:

```
Path '<Directory to which the correct workspace is mapped>...' is not under client's root '<Directory to where a different workspace is mapped>'
```

The different Perforce workspace does not have anything to do with my current project.

I can get rid of the error by closing VS, deleting the .suo file and opening the solution again, but it is really annoying to do it each time and I would like to fix it properly.

The closest question on SO I found is this one: [Perforce troubles "file not under client's root" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428521/perforce-troubles-file-not-under-clients-root-error-message), but I don't think any of the answers cover my case.

**EDIT:**

In fact I was wrong thinking that deleting the .suo file fixes the problem temporarly. I checked it building project wich was not affected anyway.
Looking at the project configuration it looks that the affected projects are from an external, shared directory. Also in the File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control... the shared projects have different Server Binding. 
The [How does Visual Studio's source control integration work with Perforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261525/how-does-visual-studios-source-control-integration-work-with-perforce) has advice on how to set up the VS-P4 binding properly. However, as my solution is quite large with multiple projects I'm reluctant to clean up all the dependencies to then start the set up from scratch. 
Would be great is anyone had a simler to implement suggestion.

Comment: Does the solution have P4 bindings in it?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor - yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the VS SCC bindings, and using [P4VS](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/visual-studio-plug-in) instead. It doesn't require any changes to the projects or the solution, and it's a much better integration with Perforce, in my experience.