# Branching gives wrong project folder

Tags: tfs

I have a problem with branching in Team Foundation Server 2013. Probably because I am a novice at TFS 2013.

Please observe the screenshot with the branches at [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx)

I have a similar setup. I simply want to branch my 'MAIN' branch by making a new branch in the 'DEV' folder. Everything goes as the tutorial said it would.

But when I open my sln file in my new dev branch the single project that is referenced in the solution is still the original project from the main branch. Why does it keep referencing the project in the MAIN?

**Source Control Explorer**

[image: Screenshot SCE]

**Solution Explorer**

[image: Screenshot SE]

**.csproj file and .sln file**
If you look in the .csproj file I indeed see:  SAK SAK SAK SAK. But if I lookin the .sln file I see: SccProjectUniqueName0 = ..\..\Projects\Company\CallManager\MAIN\SRC\WebHIS.CallManager\WebHIS.CallManager\WebHIS.CallManager.csproj SccProjectName0 = $/Company/CallManager/MAIN/SRC/WebHIS.CallManager/WebHIS.CallManager SccAuxPath0 = blabla/tfs/defaultcollection SccLocalPath0 = ..\..\Projects\Company\CallManager\MAIN\SRC\WebHIS.CallManager\WebHIS.CallManager. Could this be the problem?

**Change Source Control dialog** 
[image: Change SCD]

Comment: Are the project references absolute or relative?

Comment: @ChrisBint When I look at Project Folder in Solution Explorer it looks to me like an absolute path. Do you mean that? But I have never had problems with that before.

Comment: It would be useful if you can send a snapshot of your source code explorer. Was your .sln file in the folder that you branched or did you just branched the folder at the same level at the .sln file? Sorry, obvious question but it can be easily done.

Comment: @HamidShahid I have added screenshots. Is my question more clear now? The red circled folders are the folders the sln files are in.

Comment: @TLRonin Yes, the question is quite clear now. Thanks.
Hmmm, interesting. Please can you edit the project file (open it in notepad) and see the value of elements SccProjectName, SccLocalPath, SccAuxPath and SccProvider. Should be set to SAK for all of them as below

<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>

<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>

<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>

<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>

Comment: @HamidShahid I have also included a screenshot of the Change Source Control dialog. What puzzled me was why the solution was not under source control at all apparantly. And the project is, but the 'server binding' points to the MAIN branch. Nót the project in the DEV branch??

Comment: Not sure how it happened but you know the reason now. Just modify the solution file to use WebHIS.CallManager\WebHIS.CallManager\... and that would work out well

Comment: @HamidShahid Place your second comment in an answer, so I can award you the credits.  Because your comments + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261525/how-does-visual-studios-source-control-integration-work-with-perforce steered me into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @RLRonin. Have moved it to answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can you edit the project file (open it in notepad) and see the value of elements SccProjectName, SccLocalPath, SccAuxPath and SccProvider.

Should be set to SAK for all of them as below

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName> 
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath> 
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath> 
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Your solution file also contains the Source control project path in the element SccProjectName0. It should be set to relative path.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thanks! The only question remains 'why' did this happen. I expect to simply branch my main branch and be done with it. Not go around editting files.